# comments.json error Not Found

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm following the reactjs tutorial, and I keep running into an issue when passing the value from the state of one component into another component.
The error "comments.json" error Not Found" is thrown.

#### Comment

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
    rawMarkup: function(){
        var tt = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
        return {__html: tt};
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                    {this.props.author}
                </h2>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()}/>
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

#### CommentList

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment, key){
            return (
                <Comment key={key} author={comment.author}>
                    {comment.text}
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

#### CommentBOX

```
 var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

 ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url="comments.json" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Please note that the answer by @giovannilobitos is somewhat dangerous. See [this example](http://output.jsbin.com/wohima) which shows what can happen if you use array index as key.

Answer (score 0):

This should seal the deal.

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment, key){
            return (
                <Comment key={key} author={comment.author}>
                    {comment.text}
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: @Vijay this denies purpose of the key property.

Comment: Key makes the child elements unique, and is only with respect to the parent. Key need not be unique to the page.

Comment: @Vijay keys don't make children unique. Keys allow React to distinguish _different_ elements and plan future DOM updates